# Comparing CPU Performance - continued

Tags: performance, cpu, algebra

I already posted part c) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333525/comparing-cpu-performance)

but I am still stuck with parts d and e

> (c) A subset of the instructions for a machine M can be accelerated by n times using a coprocessor C. Given that a program P is compiled into instructions of M such that a fraction k belongs to this subset, what is the overall speedup that can be achieved using C with M?
>
> (d) Given that the coprocessor C in part (c) above costs j times as much as M, calcu- late the minimum fraction of instructions for a program that C has to accelerate so that the combined system of M and C is j times faster than M.

If I have `j = 1 / ((1-k)+k/j)` (i.e. `j` times faster) I end up with `j = 1` if I simplify the formula, which is clearly wrong

> (e) Given that the performance of M is improving by m times per month, how many months will pass before M alone (without the coprocessor C) can execute the program P in part (c) as fast as the current combined system of M and C?

Is this just `m = (1-k) + k/n`?

Thanks!

Comment: Mixing "times faster than" vs "times as fast as" in the same problem?  Bad teacher!  One wonders which "improving by `m` times" actually means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (c), you used `j` (cost difference) when you meant `n` (coprocessor advantage).  It should be:

```
s = 1 / ((1-k) + k/n)
```

For part (d), you want to set `s = (1 + j)`.  So solve `1 + j = 1 / ((1-k) + k/n)` for `k`.

For part (e), you need logarithms.  Start with `s = pow(1+m, t)`, set this equal to the speedup formula from (c) (cancelling `j` in the process), and solve for `t`.